# Read innermost value in multiple tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples

I want to **read** in the **innermost value in tuple**.

```
Input - (((False, 2), 2), 2)
Output - False
```

I want to **read** only **False** value. The **size of tuple** goes vary but I want to read only the most **innermost value** of **innermost tuple** directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using recursion:

```
def i(I):
 try:
      return i(I[0])
 except:
      return I

Input = (((False, 2), 2), 2)
print i(Input)
```

Comment: Your function will go all nuts when the first item happens to be a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the tuple using a generator function and return the first item:

```
from collections import Iterable

def solve(seq):
    for x in seq:
        if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, basestring):
            for y in solve(x):
                yield y
        else:
            yield x
...             
>>> next(solve((((False, 2), 2), 2)))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like you would in a list, using the index:

```
>>> a = (((False, 2), 2), 2)
>>> a[0][0][0]
False
```

Comment: I am sure OP is not looking for hard-coded indices.

Comment: Right @ ashwini chaudhary